# ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f70f408b3c8>: Failed to establish a new connection

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a social network with django. Every thing was working perfectly. then I changed some code in two views. one in post like_unlike_post view and profile detail view. I added SingleObjectMixin and formviwe with detail view so that people can like and comment on post when visiting others profile. after that I notice this error occurs everytime I try to login or update something. I have no idea what causing this error. Can anyone help me with this. here is my profile detail and update view

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import DetailView, RedirectView, UpdateView, FormView
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin
from .models import Profile
from posts.forms import PostModelForm, CommentModelForm
from posts.models import Post
from relationships.models import Relationship


User = get_user_model()

class ProfileDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):

    model = Profile
    slug_field = "slug"
    slug_url_kwarg = "slug"
    form_class = CommentModelForm
    queryset = Profile.objects.prefetch_related('posts__likes', 'friends', 'posts__comment_posted', 'posts__comment_posted__user')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): 
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        
        sender_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=self.request.user.id)
        receiver_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=self.object.id)
        frnd_btn_state = Relationship.objects.relation_status(
            sender=sender_profile,
            receiver=receiver_profile,
        )
        context['frnd_btn_state'] = frnd_btn_state

        context['frnd_req_rcvd'] = Relationship.objects.invitation_recieved(
            receiver = sender_profile
        )
        context['form'] = CommentModelForm()
        return context
    

class ProfilePostComment(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'profiles/profile_detail.html'
    form_class = CommentModelForm
    model = Profile

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        comment_form = CommentModelForm()
        profile=Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        if 'submit_c_form' in request.POST:
            comment_form = CommentModelForm(request.POST or None)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                instance = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                instance.user = profile
                post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
                instance.post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
                instance.save()
                comment_form = CommentModelForm()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)


    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("profiles:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.request.user.username})         

class ProfileDetailComment(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = ProfileDetailView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = ProfilePostComment.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)


profile_detail_view = ProfileDetailComment.as_view()

class ProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    model = Profile
    fields = ["name", 'bio', 'gender', 'country', 
        'favourite',
    ]

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("profiles:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.request.user.username})

    def get_object(self):
        return Profile.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.add_message(
            self.request, messages.INFO, _("Infos successfully updated")
        )
        return super().form_valid(form)


profile_update_view = ProfileUpdateView.as_view()


class ProfileRedirectView(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):

    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        return reverse("profiles:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.request.user.username})


profile_redirect_view = ProfileRedirectView.as_view()
```

And this is my post view which contains post and commenting view and like unlike view

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models import Prefetch
from django.views.generic import UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Post, Like, Comment
from profiles.models import Profile
from .forms import PostModelForm, CommentModelForm



@login_required
def post_comment_create_and_list_view(request):
    profile=Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    profile_list = Profile.get_all_friends_list(self=request.user)
    #profile contains list of the friends i have
    queryset = Post.objects.all_posts(user_id=request.user.id, profile_list=profile_list)
    

    #post form
    post_form = PostModelForm()
    if 'submit_p_form' in request.POST:
        post_form = PostModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            instance = post_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = profile
            instance.save()
            post_form = PostModelForm()
            messages.success(request, 'Post published')
            return redirect('posts:main_post_list')
    
    #comment form
    comment_form = CommentModelForm()
    if 'submit_c_form' in request.POST:
        comment_form = CommentModelForm(request.POST or None)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            instance = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = profile
            post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
            instance.post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
            instance.save()
            comment_form = CommentModelForm()
            return redirect('posts:main_post_list')

    context = {
        'queryset': queryset,
        'profile': profile,
        'post_form': post_form,
        'comment_form': comment_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/main.html', context)

        

def like_unlike_post(request):
    user = request.user
    print(user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
        post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        print(post_obj)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        print(profile)

        if profile in post_obj.likes.all():
            print(1)
            post_obj.likes.remove(profile)
        else:
            print(2)
            post_obj.likes.add(profile)

        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=profile, post_id=post_id)

        if not created:
            print(3)
            if like.value=='LIKE':
                print(4)
                like.value='UNLIKE'
            else:
                print(5)
                like.value='LIKE'
        else:
            print(6)
            like.value='LIKE'

            post_obj.save()
            like.save()

    


class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/confirm_del.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts:main_post_list')

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs.get('id')
        obj = Post.objects.get(id=id)

        if not obj.author.user == self.request.user:
            messages.warning(self.request, 'You can\'t delete others post!')
            return redirect('posts:main_post_list')
        return obj

class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = PostModelForm
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts:main_post_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user = self.request.user)
        if form.instance.author == profile:
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            form.add_error(None, 'Hey!! You are not the owner of this post!')
            return super().form_invalid(form)


class CommentDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'posts/confirm_del.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts:main_post_list')

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs.get('id')
        obj = Comment.objects.get(id=id)

        if not obj.user.user == self.request.user:
            messages.warning(self.request, 'Hey!! You are not the owner of this post!')
            return redirect('posts:main_post_list')
        return obj

class CommentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = CommentModelForm
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'posts/update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts:main_post_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user = self.request.user)
        if form.instance.user.id == profile.id:
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            form.add_error(None, 'Hey!! You are not the owner of this post!')
            return super().form_invalid(form)
```

the error I am getting

```
ConnectionError at /accounts/login/
ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f70f408b3c8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f70f408b3c8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 3.0.10
Exception Type: ConnectionError
Exception Value:    
ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f70f408b3c8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f70f408b3c8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
Exception Location: /home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/stalker/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py in perform_request, line 124
Python Executable:  /home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/stalker/env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/stalker/stalker_project',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/stalker/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/stalker/stalker_project/stalker_project',
 '/home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/stalker/stalker_project/stalker_project']
Server time:    Sat, 26 Sep 2020 12:26:55 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was using elastic search for my project and I was the reason for causing this problem. I find out when trying to create another superuser form command line. For solving this problem I had to stop elasticsearch and run it again